# ${build.target}

Tags: ros, android-gingerbread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I wanted to know what it means by build.target does not exist in android_gingenbread ?
thanks,
Vahid.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28511/$%7Bbuild.target%7D/) by [vahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1777/vahid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2012-02-25**:
Have you got line  in file manifest.xml? Have you got line target=android-10 in file project.properties?

**Comment by [vahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1777/vahid/) on 2012-02-25**:
thanks actually it was not set to 10 but was set to 9 i tried to find them but could not. thanks agina. but now i am getting another error in regard to android-9 which is :/home/vahid/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/android.xml:427: Unable to resolve target 'android-9' but I do not know where

**Comment by [vahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1777/vahid/) on 2012-02-25**:
where to look for it. I tried to move the android-9 out of the sdks so I could find all the places that are set to android-9 level api ... can you please help to find this one too, and tell me where to look, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to find all files in directory "rosjava_android" with word "target" and replace "android-9" on "android-10"

Or set target in properties project in Eclipse
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2012-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1777/vahid/) on 2012-02-25**:
i posted something down below

**Comment by [vahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1777/vahid/) on 2012-02-25**:
i tried to run it with eclipse and after i imported the android_app_chooser project i right clicked on it and hit run as android application now through eclipse i am getting Android AVD Error, NO compatible targets were found. do you wish to a add new android virtual device?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

android-9 no longer exists. You need to change the target in your manifest to android-10.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1